# Write column names to variables based on a condition

Tags: r, if-statement, apply, lapply

I have a bunch of binary variables for which I want to substitute in the column name when the variable is 1, and empty otherwise.

The data frame `before` looks like this:

```
Apple Orange Banana
0 1 0
1 1 1
1 0 0
0 0 1
```

I want to get to this (`after`):

```
Apple Orange Banana
   NA Orange     NA
Apple Orange Banana
Apple     NA     NA
   NA     NA Banana
```

I've tried using the various apply functions with no luck. For instance, I cannot figure out why this code doesn't work:

```
after <- apply(before,1,function(x) ifelse(x==1,colnames(x),NA))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ifelse` without the `apply` loop by creating a vector of `names`

```
df[] <- ifelse(df == 1L, names(df)[col(df)], NA)
```

which results in

```
#   Apple Orange Banana
# 1  <NA> Orange   <NA>
# 2 Apple Orange Banana
# 3 Apple   <NA>   <NA>
# 4  <NA>   <NA> Banana
```

Where the original `df` is

```
structure(list(Apple = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Orange = c(1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), Banana = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Apple", "Orange", 
"Banana"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also try

```
 df[] <- names(df)[(NA^!df)+col(df)-1]
 df
 # Apple Orange Banana
 #1  <NA> Orange   <NA>
 #2 Apple Orange Banana
 #3 Apple   <NA>   <NA>
 #4  <NA>   <NA> Banana
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Apple = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Orange = c(1L, 1L, 
 0L, 0L), Banana = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Apple", "Orange", 
 "Banana"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or one that is not making use of levels

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x){ifelse(x==1, names(x), NA)}))
  Apple Orange Banana
1  <NA> Orange   <NA>
2 Apple Orange Banana
3 Apple   <NA>   <NA>
4  <NA>   <NA> Banana
```

Comment: Thanks KFB, can you explain why names(x) is OK but colnames(x) throws a "replacement has length zero" error?

Comment: `colnames()` will return a NULL value inside `ifelse()`. Thus you will see "replacement has length zero"

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
m[m == 1] <- rep(colnames(m), each = 4)[(m == 1)]
m[m == 0] <- NA
m
  Apple Orange Banana
1  <NA> Orange   <NA>
2 Apple Orange Banana
3 Apple   <NA>   <NA>
4  <NA>   <NA> Banana
```